# JSON PARSING: Conditional extract key, and if it's null, fallback to other key

Tags: jq

I am a total beginner to JSON and to `jq`.

I have the following JSON document:

```json
{
  "initial": [
    {
      "HIGH": null,
      "LOW": "XXX",
      "LARGE": "yyy",
      "variant": "MAIN"
    },
    {
      "HIGH": "ACE",
      "LOW": "XXX",
      "LARGE": "yyy",
      "variant": "Loren"
    }
  ]
}
```

My code:

```bash
jq -r '.initial[] | {Rank: .HIGH, Name: .variant} | join(",")'
```

Output:

```
,MAIN
ACE,Loren
```

Expected output:

```
yyy,MAIN
ACE, Loren
```

If `HIGH` is `null`, fallback to `LARGE`, and if it's also `null`, fallback to `LOW`.

Also, if `variant` is `null` then use the default value `MAIN` instead.

Can someone help me with that?

From some tutorials I tried:

```bash
jq -r '.initial[] | {Rank: (map(if (.HIGH == null or .HIGH == "null" or .HIGH == "") then .LARGE else .HIGH end)), Name: .variant}'
```

But this gives me an error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:16): Cannot index string with string "HIGH"
```

Comment: Your code tries to create an object with the keys `Rank` and `Name`, but these appear not to be used in the expected output. Is that an oversight, or are the keys of no importance?

Answer (score 1):

You want [`//`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator://)

```bash
jq '.initial[] | [.HIGH // .LARGE // .LOW, .variant // "MAIN"] | join(",")'
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want for output is a set of CSV records with a header, you may get that by first passing the headers and then the data through the `@csv` operator:

```bash
$ jq -r '[ "Rank", "Name" ], (.initial | map([.HIGH // .LARGE // .LOW, .variant // "MAIN"]))[] | @csv' file
"Rank","Name"
"yyy","MAIN"
"ACE","Loren"
```

This uses a similar expression to extract the data as glenn uses [in their answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/721303/116858), but using  `map()` (since I like `map()` and since you appear to want to use it in your attempts too).